# CSS3 Animation on hover with transitions keyframes

Tags: css, css-transitions, keyframe

I need to make this animation smooth and more appealing.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XeELs/210/

Comment: what exactly is your problem? what do you have in mind? As far as smoothness goes, it runs perfectly in chrome.

Comment: is it? well, I just fixet myself, I was using key frames, but now I removed it...